# Executing commands after reading the response of a previous command in JSch

Tags: java, ssh, inputstream, jsch

I want to execute 2 commands using JSch but they should not go together. I am doing this to connect from a gateway to a server(thus the command ssh servername)

First command: ssh servername
Second command: password

I tried multiple approaches but they keep on stacking together.

```
        JSch jsch = new JSch();

        gateway = jsch.getSession(username, host, port);
        gateway.setPassword(password);
        gateway.setConfig(SessionPool.defaultSessionConfig());
        gateway.setHostKeyAlias(host);
        gateway.connect(20000);
        System.out.println("Session created");
channel = gateway.openChannel("shell");
        OutputStream ops = channel.getOutputStream();
        PrintStream ps = new PrintStream(ops, true);

        channel.connect();
        ps.println("ssh SERVER_NAME" + ENTER_KEY);

        ps.println(PASSWORD + ENTER_KEY);

        ps.close();

        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        byte[] bt = new byte[1024];

        while (true) {

            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(bt, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)
                    break;
                String str = new String(bt, 0, i);
                // displays the output of the command executed.
                System.out.print(str);

            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {

                break;
            }

        }
```

Comment: You say you're trying to run two commands, but I only see one ("ssh SERVER_NAME") in the code that you posted. Can you describe how the program is failing? Are you getting any error messages? Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: the second command is the password to the SERVER that I am trying to connect to with SERVER_NAME. There is no error. The 2 commands just go together and not simultaneously as I wanted. The plan here is that the second command executes after the prompt that the first command generated. I cannot seem to figure it out.

Comment: There's no error? Then what happens when you run your program?

Comment: I cannot connect to the supposedly 2nd server which is triggered by the command ssh SERVER_NAME because the password is entered after the command and not after the prompt

Comment: It runs normally, executing both of the commands. but not the way I want it to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Putting Thread.sleep between commands does the trick =)